# How to install "Windows Phone Developer Tools RTW" without installing Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, sdk, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

Is it possible to install "Windows Phone Developer Tools RTW" on a machine without installing Visual Studio and Expression Blend?

The reason I am asking is that I want to install it on a build server.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=04704acf-a63a-4f97-952c-8b51b34b00ce&displaylang=en

Comment: Does the download from that link require VS or Expression Blend?  It shoudln't.

Comment: @Michael - no, but the Windows Phone download is harder to fathom - see http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=04704acf-a63a-4f97-952c-8b51b34b00ce&displaylang=en

Comment: @Steve: I was confused what you were talking about with the Windows Phone download since it has nothing to do with the SDK, but now I see there are some Windows Phone tags on the question...  So I guess I should be confused.

Comment: @Michael, yes I'm guessing that's of interest to @Simon. Looks like MS is currently targeting desktop development/build only for this?

Comment: @Steve: I don't know what MS is doing for Phone development other than a lot of people seemed angry/confused that VS2010 had no support. It's possible that MS's story for scripted builds involves installing the "Phone Developer Tools" to the build server and just ignoring the IDE (invoking msbuild or something). But since I've never done any Win Phone development I really don't know.

Comment: @Michael - same here.  Hopefully some domain experts can chime in.

Comment: @All sorry guys. I had the wrong link... I screwed up. Have fixed the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download and install the tools and then uninstall any options you don't require. Such as VS2010Express & Blend.

Unfortunately there isn't a better solution available at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's exactly why downloads like the one you referenced exist - build servers, production servers have to build/run without Visual Studio.

Do you have specific needs here?  I see the q is tagged for Windows Phone.

Online info about the Windows Phone developer tools seems to indicate that it's currently a bit of a work in progress. Don't see any obvious way to put this standalone on a build machine.

Comment: The reference to the "shaft[ing]" of VS RTM was an issue with the CTP if you subsequently installed VSpro. THe RTM tools do not have this problem.